# What is the correct way to receive payment gateway response via POST method

Tags: payment-gateway, cs-cart

I'm trying to create a new payment gateway for CS-Cart 4. The issue I'm facing right now is how to capture the response from the gateway which uses POST.

Some code snippets:

```
$status =$_POST['status'];
$orderid =$_POST['orderid'];

if ( $status == "SUCCESS" ) {
  fn_change_order_status($orderid, 'P');
  fn_finish_payment($orderid, $_POST, false);
  fn_order_placement_routines('route',$orderid,false);
}
```

I don't think Cs-cart is capturing these POST variables as my orders are still shown as Incomplete, although I can confirm its status as SUCCESS on the gateway side.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know whats the returns vars method are using to capture the data $_GET or $_POST, anyway you can check with a $_REQUEST[''] or $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], then you can use according the values and status indicated for the merchant account:

```
   $status =$_POST['status'];
   $orderid =$_POST['orderid'];

   if ( $status == "SUCCESS" ) {
     fn_change_order_status($orderid, 'P');
     fn_finish_payment($orderid, $_POST, false);
     fn_order_placement_routines('route',$orderid,false);
   }
```